# Perl: Rearrange array based on element value

Tags: arrays, perl, splice

What would be the most efficient way to rearrange the array elements so that they are ordered & place with the corresponding index value (minus one)? The $dat variable being the max number of elements (which is never exceeded in the array but may or may not be present).

```
$dat = 14;  
my @array = (1, 12, 14, 7, 8, 4)
```

In other words:

```
my @new_array = (1, undef, undef, 4, undef, undef, 7, 8, undef, undef, undef, 12, undef, 14);
```

***EDIT****
Fuller code snippet:

```
foreach $auth (keys %activity) {
my @value = @{ $activity{$auth} };
@value = uniq @value;
@value = sort @value;
s/^0// for @value;

my $count = scalar(grep $_, @value);
my $dat = max( @value );
@{$activity{$auth}} = @value;
}
```

Comment: Is it always running from 1 up to `$dat`?

Comment: values within the array may differ from time to time (but never exceeding dat).  I've tried some variations of "If" but it's really messy. I seem to be stuck on removing the existing array index after moving the value to its new position

Comment: `sort` should probably come before `uniq`

Comment: @infixed, No way. Better to reduce the number of elements to sort first.

Comment: I'm used to the shell command `uniq` that strips repeated lines.  You wouldn't get repeated lines without sorting. I suppose there are `perl` functions that are more flexible, the one used in the question isn't specified.   I frankly thought it was listed in `perlfunc`, and was similar to the shell command, but its not.

Comment: @infixed, It's probably the one provided by List::Util, which does not require a sorted list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create an new array with all values defined after finding the maximum value in the first, then in this new array undefine any value which is not in the first:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;


my @array =  ('1', '4', '3');
my $max = (sort { $b <=> $a } @array)[0]; #should be 4

print Dumper(\@array);

my @new_arr;
foreach my $index (0 .. ($max - 1)) {
   $new_arr[$index] = ($index + 1);    
       #Array should be fully populated, @new_arr = ('1', '2', '3', '4');
   $new_arr[$index] = 'undef' unless (grep {$_ eq $new_arr[$index]} @array); 
       #Values not in the original array should be set to undef

}
#  @new_arr should be (''1', 'undef', '3', '4')

print Dumper(\@new_arr);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          '4',
          '3'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          1,
          'undef',
          3,
          4
        ];
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for efficient solutions, and this is far less efficient (O(N^2)) than the previously-submitted answers (O(N)). This is an awful solution.

Comment: I honestly think your solutions look awful as well, and quite inelegant. Three separate implementations for different usage conditions, with nested else/if loops and i/j indices ... mine works for all conditions; removing the duplicates if present and completing the required task.

Comment: It sure is strange how he gave me the green-check then ... How can you say it doesn't do what he asks, I have a sample code snippet along with proper output shown above.  I understand that big-o notation yours are 'more efficient' however big-o is not the only measure of efficiency.  Also I am not competing with you.  I gave a solution which solved his problem.  Based on your rep apparently this site means a lot to you and you just can't handle someone else's answer getting the green check?

Comment: Pointing out that I have solutions that work in the scenarios when yours only works in one of those three scenarios is not helpful to your cause. // Pointing out that the OP doesn't realize how inefficient your solution is not productive. // If you have comments about my answer,  they should be posted there.

Comment: My solution works for all scenarios, try it yourself if you need to.  Your solution is really three solutions.  One measure of efficiency is brevity.  Regardless, I know that your solutions will be faster according to big-0 notation, I have never disputed this.  You are the person who started commenting on MY solution, the moment it was given the green check over yours.  In fact you have been a great resource in the past.  It is just such a shame to learn what a jackass you are.

Comment: No, you're doesn't work in-place, while two of mine do. // Brevity is a measure of maintaining, not efficiency.

Comment: Seems to work for me, I have the code snippet up there with output.  In-place afaik refers to editing a file in-place; I am unfamiliar with it in this context.

Comment: It means changing @array without using any extra memory. (I'm not saying that it's required; I'm saying that  also providing solutions that are memory-efficient is not a bad thing)

Comment: Well you got me there then.

Answer (score 2):

Simple and fast (duplicates may occur in the original):

```
my @new_array;
$new_array[$_ - 1] = $_ for @array;
```

---

In-place (duplicates not allowed in original):

```
for (my $i = @array; $i--; ) {
   my $j = $array[$i]-1;
   if ($i < $j) {
      $array[$j] = $j+1;
      $array[$i] = undef;
   }
   elsif ($i > $j) {
      @array[$i, $j] = @array[$j, $i];
      redo;
   }
}
```

---

In-place (duplicates may occur in the original):

```
for (my $i = @array; $i--; ) {
   my $j = $array[$i]-1;
   if ($i < $j) {
      $array[$j] = $j+1;
      $array[$i] = undef;
   }
   elsif ($i > $j) {
      if ($array[$j] == $j+1) {
         $array[$i] = undef;
      }
      else {
         @array[$i, $j] = @array[$j, $i];
         redo;
      }
   }
}

pop(@array) while @array && !defined($array[-1]);
```

Comment: From comments it seems that user might want to do it in-place. Though it would make task some kind of puzzle/golf rather than somewhat realistic one instead.

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, Then add `@array = @new_array;`

Comment: @Oleg V. Volkov, In-place solution added.